# Windows internet sharing uses 50% of my CPU

Tags: windows-7, performance, internet-sharing

I discovered that svhost.exe process is using almost 50% of my CPU time when computer was almost idle - I was downloading big file with USB 3G modem with 80kB/s speed.

I have relatively fast CPU (Intel Core 2 Duo 2.5GHz T9300, it does SuperPi 1M benchmark in 17 seconds).

To find reason I was turning off services related with svhost one by one. Finally, when I turned off Internet Connection Sharing service my "idle" CPU load dropped to normal (0-1%).

Im using Internet Connection Sharing sometimes to share internet from USB modem to other computer connected with ethernet, but when I had 50% load there was no network activity at all and I had my network disconnected.

**What is wrong with my Internet Connection Sharing service?**

Comment: What operating system?  Does this happen with a minimal boot configuration?

Comment: It's Windows 7. I think minimal boot configuration will not start ICS, so... It will not happen I guess.

Comment: The T9300 is an ancient CPU. That said, it shouldn't take 50% CPU to do this. Curious, are you using the latest drivers for your USB modem?

Comment: @Kamil - You can start it manually.  The point is to rule out everything except ICS.

Comment: @Ramhound Yea, I know I can control ICS manually, but I asked because I want to find reason.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I know thats not latest i7, but it is really fast cpu. For single or two core applications T9xxx series is compareable to latest AMD processors overclocked to 4Ghz+. I guess im not using latest modem drivers, I will try to update drivers.

Comment: I am trying to get you to do troubleshooting.  But I can't determine the cause if you don't at least try what I am asking.'

Comment: try updating the network card drivers

Comment: Many internet-related things will practically kill that CPU. The way they are now, it's inevitable. Good thing it's not a single core, as it would be on 100% load.